# how to improve the performance Machine Learning - DQ learning model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

The lunar lander on DQlearning doesn't perform well, so I try to improve the performance of lunar lander (dq learning) by optimising the parameters to make it better. Which part can I adjust? could anyone provide some ideas for me? add more layers or change the activation type or others methods??

here is the code:

```py
import numpy as np
import gym
import csv

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import Adam

from rl.agents.dqn import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy, EpsGreedyQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory

import io
import sys
import csv

# Path environment changed to make things work properly
# export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib


# Get the environment and extract the number of actions.
ENV_NAME = 'LunarLander-v2'
env = gym.make(ENV_NAME)
np.random.seed(123)
env.seed(123)
nb_actions = env.action_space.n

# Next, we build a very simple model.
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(1,) + env.observation_space.shape))
model.add(Dense(16))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(16))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(16))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dense(nb_actions))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
print(model.summary())

# Finally, we configure and compile our agent. You can use every built-in Keras optimizer and
# even the metrics!
memory = SequentialMemory(limit=300000, window_length=1)
policy = EpsGreedyQPolicy()
dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, nb_actions=nb_actions, memory=memory, nb_steps_warmup=10,
               target_model_update=1e-2, policy=policy)
dqn.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])

dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=30000, visualize=True, verbose=2)

# After training is done, we save the final weights.
dqn.save_weights('dqn_{}_weights.h5f'.format(ENV_NAME))

# Redirect stdout to capture test results
old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = mystdout = io.StringIO()

# Evaluate our algorithm for a few episodes.
dqn.test(env, nb_episodes=200, visualize=False)

# Reset stdout
sys.stdout = old_stdout

results_text = mystdout.getvalue()

# Print results text
print("results")
print(results_text)

# Extact a rewards list from the results
total_rewards = list()
for idx, line in enumerate(results_text.split('\n')):
    if idx > 0 and len(line) > 1:
        reward = float(line.split(':')[2].split(',')[0].strip())
        total_rewards.append(reward)

# Print rewards and average
print("total rewards", total_rewards)
print("average total reward", np.mean(total_rewards))

# Write total rewards to file
f = open("lunarlander_rl_rewards.csv",'w')
wr = csv.writer(f)
for r in total_rewards:
     wr.writerow([r,])
f.close()
```

Thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try to adjust the reward. As far as I remember lunar lander outputs quite awkward rewards up to 100. The rewards for RL should better be in the range of -1 to 1. Try to scale it down or to change it.

Other parameters worth optimizing first are the learning rate and the exploration rate.

Comment: what about the activation function, dense and the number of layers?

Comment: @HungryBird You can try using 2 layers with 50 or 100 channels with only relu activations. Also try training for at least 1e6 environment steps

Comment: Thanks, I will try